# How can I make the background of an HTML div black?

Tags: jquery, html, css, visual-studio, webmatrix-3

I'm dynamically loading some HTML stored on disk into a div like so:

```
$('#FictionContent').load('Content/HuckFinn.html');
```

To give some context:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#tabs').tabs({
                beforeActivate: function(event, ui) {
                    if (ui.newTab.index() == 0) { // index 0 is fiction
                        $('#body').removeClass('bronzeBackground silverBackground goldBackground').addClass
('bronzeBackground');
                        $('#FictionContent').load('Content/HuckFinn.html');
```

FictionContent is defined like this:

```
<div id="FictionContent" class="clearfix">Content in Fiction tab</div>
```

And here it is with some context:

```
<div id="tabs" class="content-wrapper">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#tab-Fiction">Fiction</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab-Nonfiction">Nonfiction</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab-MiscTwain">Miscellaneous</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="tab-Fiction">
    <select id="fictionDropDown">
        <option value="HuckFinn">Huck Finn</option>
        <option value="TomSawyer">Tom Sawyer</option>
        <option value="tPatP">Prince and the Pauper</option>
        <option value="ConnYank">Connecticut Yankee</option>
        <option value="Gilded">The Gilded Age</option>
        <option value="Puddnhead">Pudd'nhead Wilson</option>
        <option value="ShortStories">Short Stories</option>
    </select>
    <div id="FictionContent" class="clearfix">Content in Fiction tab</div>
</div>
```

The clearfix CSS class used by FictionContent is in Site.css was this:

```
.clearfix:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;
}
```

I added this to it:

```
background-color: black;
```

...but to no avail - did not change the background color.

I also tried adding this to the top of the HTML file I'm loading (HuckFinn.html):

```
<style>
    background-color: black;
</style>
<h1>The Adventures of Huckleberry Finn</h1>
```

With some context:

```
<style>
    background-color: black;
</style>
<h1>The Adventures of Huckleberry Finn</h1>

<h3>Scene:  The Mississippi Valley Time:  Forty to fifty years ago</h3>
. . .
```

This didn't work, either.

So how can I make the background black, as I do [here](http://jsfiddle.net/clayshannon/tL4s1hjr/127/):

?

Comment: You did not add a background to elements with the class `clearfix`, but only to the `:after` pseudo element defined for elements with that class … and since that has `height:0`, you of course don’t see much of that background color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple fix would also be to add this after your load line in your JS.

```
 $('#FictionContent').css('background-color', '#000000');
```

Answer (score 5):

In your first attempt you added the css to a pseudo element (see http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_elements.asp ).
The other 2 attempts with < style > added it to nothing in particular.
 Use

```
#FictionContent {
  background: black;
}
```

Append to your CSS file, aking it look like this:

```
.clearfix:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;
}

#FictionContent {
 background: black;
}
```